# How do I find this span with selenium in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Just wondering how to get the span text out of this div when using selenium in python.

```
<div class="clsFrameworkElement" 
id="ManagedQuestionViewer.brdrQuestion1.QuestionRenderer.MultiChoiceQuestionViewer.sp.StackPanel.RadioTextRegionViewer2.LayoutRoot.Panel.text.sp.rich.LayoutRoot.TextBlock" style="overflow: visible; display: inherit; text-shadow: white 0px 1px; left: 46px; top: 105px; border-width: 0px; width: 186px; height: 15px; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9.6pt; text-overflow: clip; overflow-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal; user-select: none;">
<span style="">Get a non-disclosure agreement.</span>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to get the span element.

Please see below snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver =  webdriver.Chrome()
html_content = """
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
         <div class="clsFrameworkElement" id="ManagedQuestionViewer.brdrQuestion1.QuestionRenderer.MultiChoiceQuestionViewer.sp.StackPanel.RadioTextRegionViewer2.LayoutRoot.Panel.text.sp.rich.LayoutRoot.TextBlock" style="overflow: visible; display: inherit; text-shadow: white 0px 1px; left: 46px; top: 105px; border-width: 0px; width: 186px; height: 15px; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9.6pt; text-overflow: clip; overflow-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal; user-select: none;">
            <span style="">Get a non-disclosure agreement.</span>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))

node = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='clsFrameworkElement']/span")
print(node.text)
```

This will print :

```
Get a non-disclosure agreement.
```

You can read more about xpath here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html